# Prove by Taylor expansion or mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, rolles-theorem

If a particle moving on the Euclidean line traverses distance $1$ in time $1$ starting and ending at rest, then at some time $t \in [0, 1]$, the absolute value of its acceleration should be at least $4$.

Please give me a hint to proceed

Comment: It's enough to show there exists t$\in[0,1] $ s''(t)=4 or -4

Comment: Why ask the same question twice? [Duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2844505/related-rate-problem-absolute-value-of-its-acceleration-should-be-at-least-4).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are given the functional form $v$ of the speed. Scalar acceleration $a$ is the derivative $v'$ of the speed. Then by the mean value theorem, for every pair of $\xi, \eta \in (0,1)$ there is some $c \in [\xi,\eta]$ such that $v(\xi) - v(\eta) = a(c)(\xi - \eta)$. Can you proceed?

Comment: I'm still stuck...

Comment: If we work only on $v$ and $a$, we discard the information on $s$ (i.e. $s(0) = 0, s(1) = 1$) which I think is fundamental...

Comment: Yes i agree with the_candyman